# Open the same view from different view controllers

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have the following scenario: I have a view controller and want to navigate programmatically to another view f.e. to give the user the ability to change settings.
So I have VC1 and VC_settings and a present modally segue between those controllers. I gave the segue an identifier and call it like this:

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "SegueToSettingsView)
```

Ok, that works without any problems. The settings view is opened and I can navigate back to VC1.

Now I want to have the same functionality in another view controller VC2. I want to reuse the settings view but the problem is that the segue is already connected between VC1 and VC_settings and I can't connect a new one for VC2.
And if I try to call the existing segue with the coce above in VC2 then the app crashes.

Answer (score 0):

In swift it is possible to create segues from multiple views two one viewcontroller. Here I have set it so there are segues from VC1 to Settings and VC2 to settings which should work.
[image]

Hope it helped

Comment: Unfortunately your screenshot is a bit confusing for me because you only show the dependencies. But can you please describe the steps in Xcode or give a little code snippet how to create/use the segues?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have VC1 and VC_settings connected with segue named "SegueToSettingsView" also the perform selector is working fine.

As per your need make another segue from VC2 to VC_Settings and give a different name for it. then make use of below code to perform segue.

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "SegueToSettingsViewFromVC2")
```

Steps to make **segue**:
[image]
**Then select the connection and set identifier**

[image]

Comment: Yes, that was my first idea. But the problem is if I select VC_settings, look under the connections tab and "presenting segues" then I will see that "presenting modally" is already connected. That's clear because it's connected to VC1 but it seems not possible to make a second segue for the same task?

Comment: It will come under viewcontroller from where you performing the segue.

Comment: definitly you can make anty number of segues as possible